# Using pairwise.adonis2 for pairwise comparisons between specific factor levels

Tags: r, vegan

I have a data frame which I am using for community analysis that looks like:

```
df<-structure(list(Sample = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "B1", 
"B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "D1", "D2", 
"D3", "D4", "D5"), Depth = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50), Year = c(2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2023, 2023, 
2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023), Sp1 = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0, 12, 16, 6, 8, 4), Sp2 = c(3, 
7, 9, 2, 6, 4, 5, 9, 4, 3, 6, 8, 6, 4, 7, 9, 2, 5, 3, 3), Sp3 = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), Sp4 = c(11, 
32, 12, 17, 5, 0, 13, 19, 3, 4, 5, 0, 24, 20, 15, 3, 2, 0, 1, 
8), Sp5 = c(5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 8, 1, 1, 1, 0, 12, 6, 3, 8, 6, 
2, 0, 1, 2), Sp6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 3, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 15, 12, 4, 8, 11)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I split this into just species counts in one df and factors in another using:

```
library(tidyverse)

factor.df = df %>%
as.data.frame()

row.names(factor.df) <- factor.df$Sample

factor.df = factor.df %>%
select(1:3)

species.df <- df %>% 
dplyr::select(-Depth, -Year, -Sample)
```

I am running PERMANOVA on this using adonis and pairwise adonis:

```
library(vegan)

adonis<-adonis2(formula = species.df ~ Depth*Year, data = factor.df, permutations = 9999, method = "bray") 
adonis

library(pairwiseAdonis)

pairwise.adonis<-pairwise.adonis2(species.df ~ Depth/Year, data = factor.df)
pairwise.adonis
```

My question is, is there a way to look at pairwise comparisons for each level of each factor individually? So, whether there's a significant difference between communities in 2020 and 2023 at just 10m and just 50m? At the moment I can see overall differences between year and depth, but my aim is to see whether communities at different depths are differentially affected by year. Any help much appreciated!